# Message passing chrome extension

Tags: google-chrome-extension, sendmessage

I wants to create an extension where content script will send message to background page and then on browser action means clicking on extension icon will access that background page and get some data.I am using chrome Version 23.0.1271.64 m on windows8.

I am getting following error.
Port error: Could not establish connection. Receiving end does not exist.

I tried to solve the same. but people are using sendRequest which is not supported by chrome20+. i also found solution mentioned for chrome 20+. But not working. Please help.

Below is the file contents.

**manifest.json**

```
{
  "name": "Test Extension",
  "version": "1.0",
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "description": "A test extension.",
  "background": "background.html",
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
      "js": ["jquery.js","content.js"]
    }
  ],
 "permissions": ["tabs", "http://*/", "https://*/"],
   "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "icon.png",
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
  }
}
```

**background.html**

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="background.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Wy</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

**background.js**

```
chrome.extension.onMessage.addListener(function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
    // Chrome 20+
    alert(request);
    console.log('received in listener');
  sendResponse({farewell: "goodbye"});

});
```

**content.js**

```
$(function(){
console.log('start-sending message');

chrome.extension.sendMessage({greeting: "hello"},function(response){alert(response);});

console.log('end-sending message');
});
```

**popup.html**

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Getting Started Extension's Popup</title>
    </style>

    <!-- JavaScript and HTML must be in separate files for security. -->
    <script src="jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="popup.js"></script>

  </head>
  <body>
  </body>
</html>
```

**popup.js**

```
$(function(){
  var str_html = "<tr><td width='60%'>S</td><td width='40%'>15</td></tr><tr><td width='60%'>M</td><td width='40%'>25</td></tr>";
  $('#sizes_container').html(str_html);
  var bkg = chrome.extension.getBackgroundPage();
    console.log(bkg);
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're incorrectly mixing the deprecated `"background_page"` property with the new signature of `"background"`. The correct way to use [background pages](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/background_pages.html) is:

```
"background": {
    "scripts": ["background.js"]
}
```

You can completely get rid off your `background.html`, because it serves no purpose (the content of your `<body>` is unused) (if you really need it, use `"background": {"page": "background.html"}`).

About `sendRequest`, it is indeed deprecated, but not removed (yet).

Regarding your popup page: You don't have any element with ID `sizes_container`, so you will obviously not see any output.